# Binding "not null" in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I recently found out that you can bind null values in PDO:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = :bar');
$stmt->execute(array(':bar'=>null));
$foo = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

This would successfully fetch all `foo` from the database, where the `bar` column is null.

However, I would now like to do the opposite. I would like to fetch all columns where the `bar` column is *not* null.

I am aware I could simply replace `bar = :bar` with `bar IS NOT NULL`. However, I would like to avoid that, and instead do it through prepared statements, because I sometimes have to build the query string dynamically and having to do it manually would be a lot of extra work.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could use query builder library like [pixie](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/pixie) and then you could build dynamic queries easily or make your own query builder

Comment: You build two statements then, one where you pass values and the other where you use `IS NOT NULL`. PDO will **quote** the parameters.

Comment: @Mjh PDO/MySQL will *treat the parameters as values*. There may or may not be any quoting involved; ideally there isn't any quoting involved if you're using native prepared statements. It's simply a difference in treating parameters as part of the syntax or as values.

Comment: @deceze looking at the code OP posted, PDO will **quote** the parameters. There's no implicit stating of what the parameter type is.

Comment: @Mjh Understand that prepared statements are a native API supported by the database. The database itself will receive the prepared statement and the bound values separately. They're not even actually concatenated into the query string, hence there's no need for quoting them! That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @deceze - I don't know why this teaching lesson went the way it did, but it appears you are saying that I somehow suggested that the OP is supposed to *quote* the values or something. I am very well aware how PDO works and what prepared statements are, but thank you for clarifying anyway. The code given by the OP will force either the database or PDO itself to *quote* the values. Do recall that PDO emulates prepared statements in certain cases. Anyway, it appears that the answer has been given and world is a peaceful place again, have a nice day :)

Comment: @Mjh Yes, with emulated prepares PDO will indeed actually quote the values. Maybe I'm too nitpicky, but I'm saying there's no "quoting" involved if native prepared statements are used. Quotes are only necessary to delimit values inside of a literal SQL statement. However, if the database natively receives `SELECT ... WHERE foo = :foo` and `abcdef` as separate parameters, quotes aren't used anywhere. It will *behave as if quoted*, but there are no actual quotes at any point. Anyway, again, I'm just nitpicky.

Comment: Does `... WHERE foo = NULL` actually work? I don't think so.

Comment: @deceze - since we went this far, I suggest turning MySQL's general log on, preparing a statement with a string parameter and executing it. I'm talking about doing this from MySQL terminal. Even thought what you're referring to is almost correct, do pay attention to the step `Execute` in the log - now **that** is what I am referring to and that is usually the best way to explain what prepared statements actually do. It might explain why we are out of sync when talking about statements. I know the query is lexed once and values are "fed" to it in a safe manner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot bind "NOT NULL". You can only bind *values*. "IS NOT NULL" is not a value, it's completely different query syntax. You will simply have to dynamically build your query, value binding cannot help you with that:

```
$query = 'SELECT ... WHERE ';
if (/* condition is NOT NULL */) {
    $query .= 'foo IS NOT NULL';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
} else {
    $query .= 'foo = :foo';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue('foo', $foo);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Alright, I guess that settles it. I thought this would be harder than it actually was. Thanks for the help.

Comment: thank you for the straight answer

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid you are wrong with your assumption. Although you can bind NULL values in general, `WHERE bar = NULL` statement won't return you any rows, neither with raw SQL or PDO. This whole statement will be evaluated to NULL and won't match any row.

Instead, you can use a NULL-safe equal to operator, `<=>`, to match fields that are either NULL or have some value. But to have values that are not null, you still have to have another query.